# Generic TableView/DataFrame like functionality for plain array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, dataframe, templates, generics, tableview

I'm trying to make light-weight layer **on top of continuous array of arbitrary structs** (lets call it `DataItem`), which will handle common operations like file-IO, rendering on screen/GUI (like excel table), searching and sorting by difernet properties etc.

But I want to make my `class Table` and user-defined struct/class `DataItem` to be **completely independent of each other** (i.e. both can compile without knowing each others header-file `.h` ). I think **it cannot be like** `template<class T> class Table{ std::vectro<T> data;};` because then user would be obligated to implement functionality like `DataItem::toString(int icolumn)` and I don't want to put that constrain on  DataItem struct.

My current implementation rely on **pointer arithmetics**, `switch`, and can handle only few types of data members (bool,int,float,double). I wonder if **e.g. using templates** this could be improved (to make it more generic, safe etc...) without considerably increasing complexity and performance cost.

I want to use it like this:

```
#include "Table.h"
#include "GUI.h"
#include "Vec3d.h"

// example of user defined DataItem struct
struct TestStruct{ 
    int    inum = 115;
    double dnum = 11.1154546;
    double fvoid= 0.0;
    float  fnum = 11.115;
    Vec3d  dvec = (Vec3d){ 1.1545, 2.166, 3.1545};
};

int main(){

    // ==== Initialize test data
    Table* tab1 = new Table();
    tab1->n      =  120;
    TestStruct* tab_data = new TestStruct[tab1->n];
    for(int i=0; i<tab1->n; i++){ 
       tab_data[i].inum = i; 
       tab_data[i].fnum = i*0.1; 
       tab_data[i].dnum = i*0.01; 
    }

    // ==== Bind selected properties/members of TestStruct as columns int the table
    tab1->bind(tab_data, sizeof(*tab_data) );
    // This is actually quite complicated =>
    // I would be happy if it could be automatized by some template magic ;-)
    tab1->addColum( &(tab_data->inum), 1, DataType::Int    );
    tab1->addColum( &(tab_data->fnum), 1, DataType::Float  );
    tab1->addColum( &(tab_data->dnum), 1, DataType::Double );
    tab1->addColum( &(tab_data->dvec), 3, DataType::Double );

    // ==== Visualize the table Table in GUI
    gui.addPanel( new TableView( tab1, "tab1", 150.0, 250.0,  0, 0, 5, 3 ) );
    gui.run();

}
```

**My current implementation looks like this:**

```
enum class DataType{ Bool, Int, Float, Double, String };

struct Atribute{
    int      offset;  // offset of data member from address of struct instance [bytes]
    int      nsub;    // number of sub units. e.g. 3 for Vec3
    DataType type;    // type for conversion
    Atribute() = default;
    Atribute(int offset_,int nsub_,DataType type_):offset(offset_),nsub(nsub_),type(type_){};
};

class Table{ public:
    int n;              // number of items/lines in table
    int   itemsize = 0; // number of bytes per item
    char* data     = 0; // pointer to data buffer with structs; type is erased to make it generic  

    std::unordered_map<std::string,int> name2column;
    std::vector       <Atribute>        columns;

    void bind(void* data_, int itemsize_){
        data=(char*)data_;
        itemsize=itemsize_;
    }

    int addColum(void* ptr, int nsub, DataType type){
        // determine offset of address of given data-member with respect to address of enclosing struct
        int offset = ((char*)ptr)-((char*)data);
        columns.push_back( Atribute( offset, nsub, type ) );
        return columns.size()-1;
    }

    char* toStr(int i, int j, char* s){
        const Atribute& kind = columns[j];
        void* off = data+itemsize*i+kind.offset; // address of j-th member of i-th instance in data array
        // I don't like this switch, 
        // but still it seems simpler and more efficient that alternative solutions using 
        // templates/lambda function or function pointers
        switch(kind.type){
            case DataType::Bool   :{ bool*   arr=(bool  *)off; for(int i=0; i<kind.nsub; i++){ s+=sprintf(s,"%c ",  arr[i]?'T':'F' ); }} break;
            case DataType::Int    :{ int*    arr=(int   *)off; for(int i=0; i<kind.nsub; i++){ s+=sprintf(s,"%i ",  arr[i] ); }} break;
            case DataType::Float  :{ float*  arr=(float *)off; for(int i=0; i<kind.nsub; i++){ s+=sprintf(s,"%g ",  arr[i] ); }} break;
            case DataType::Double :{ double* arr=(double*)off; for(int i=0; i<kind.nsub; i++){ s+=sprintf(s,"%g ",  arr[i] ); }} break;
            case DataType::String :{ char*   arr=(char  *)off; for(int i=0; i<kind.nsub; i++){ s+=sprintf(s,"%s ",  arr[i] ); }} break;
        }
        return s;
    }
};

    // .... Ommited most of TableView GUI ....

    void TableView::render(){
        Draw  ::setRGB( textColor );
        char stmp[1024];
        for(int i=i0; i<imax;i++){
            int ch0 = 0;
            for(int j=j0; j<jmax;j++){
                int nch = table->toStr(i,j,stmp)-stmp; // HERE!!! I call Table::toStr()
                Draw2D::drawText( stmp, nch, {xmin+ch0*fontSizeDef, ymax-(i-i0+1)*fontSizeDef*2}, 0.0,  GUI_fontTex, fontSizeDef );
                ch0+=nchs[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you provide a sample `Table.cc`, `Table.h`, `DataItem.cc`, `DataItem.h`, and possibly a `prog.cc` using them, all of them minimalist, for what you want.
What you gave is a rough proxy to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of solving this type of problem is by providing a "traits" class which tells one class how to deal with another class without having to modify the second class. This pattern is used extensively in the standard library.

Your code could be written as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

template <typename T>
struct TableTraits;

template <typename T>
class Table
{
public:
  void setData( const std::vector<T>& value )
  {
    data = value;
  }

  std::string toString( size_t row, size_t column )
  {
    return TableTraits<T>::toString( data[ row ], column );
  }

  void print()
  {
    for ( size_t row = 0; row < data.size(); row++ )
    {
      for ( size_t column = 0; column < TableTraits<T>::columns; column++ )
      {
        std::cout << toString( row, column ) << ", ";
      }
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
  }
private:
  std::vector<T> data;
};

struct TestStruct
{
  int    inum = 115;
  double dnum = 11.1154546;
  double fvoid = 0.0;
  float  fnum = 11.115f;
  std::array<double, 3> dvec = { 1.1545, 2.166, 3.1545 };
};

template <typename T>
std::string stringConvert( const T& value )
{
  return std::to_string( value );
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
std::string stringConvert( const std::array<T, N>& value )
{
  std::string result;
  for ( auto& v : value )
  {
    result += stringConvert( v ) + "; ";
  }
  return result;
}

template <>
struct TableTraits<TestStruct>
{
  static const size_t columns = 5;

  static std::string toString( const TestStruct& row, size_t column )
  {
    switch ( column )
    {
    case 0:
      return stringConvert( row.inum );
    case 1:
      return stringConvert( row.dnum );
    case 2:
      return stringConvert( row.fvoid );
    case 3:
      return stringConvert( row.fnum );
    case 4:
      return stringConvert( row.dvec );
    default:
      throw std::invalid_argument( "column out of range" );
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<TestStruct> data( 10 );
  Table<TestStruct> table;
  table.setData( data );
  table.print();
}
```

The exact details of the traits class could be different if this example doesn't exactly meet your needs.

You might also find it useful to have the traits methods and constants non-static so that you can pass a traits object into your table to allow customisation per table instance.

You might also want to allow use of a custom traits class in your table, something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename Traits = TableTraits<T>>
class Table
{
...
  std::string toString( size_t row, size_t column )
  {
    return Traits::toString( data[ row ], column );
  }
```

Comment: This is very nice, I learned something here. Thanks! .... But what I actually wanted was something where I can add/remove columns dynamically at run-time. Or re-bind the table to array of different type of structs. But I did not specify it clearly, because I only now realized that it is main issue.

Comment: If you made your traits class non-static then it would be possible to change the values it returns at runtime. Changing the table type wouldn't be possible with templates, you could use something similar and have a virtual base traits class which you could specialise for each data struct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you are trying to use dynamic polymorphism (at run-time) using C-like structures and C-like polymorphism in C++. Templates are useful for static polymorphism. The proper direction is to use OOP (especially class polymorphism), defining concepts as classes: table, cell, column, row, cell-value, etc. As examples, you can check on Github:

- [OpenXLSX](https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX/tree/master/library/openxlsx/interfaces/c%2B%2B/headers)
- [Spreadsheets-Lower](https://github.com/code-hunger/Spreadsheets-Lower/tree/master)